# How to scope polymorphic association by attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, polymorphic-associations

I want to write scope based on attribute from polymorphic association.

I have models:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :person, polymorphic: true

end

class Teacher < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :items, as: :person

end

class Student < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :items, as: :person

end
```

Both **Teacher** and **Student** have attribute **name** and i want to use that attribute for scope like:

```
scope :by_name, ->(name) { joins(:person).where(persons: {name: name}) }
```

Is there any way to scope this nicely since i can't just mentioned scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a really clean way of doing this... this is clunky but should work but it's not nicely expandable.  Hopefully somone has a better answer.

```
scope :by_name, ->(name) { joins("left join teachers on person_type = 'Teacher' and person_id = teachers.id")
                          .joins("left join students on person_type = 'Student' and person_id = students.id")
                          .where('teachers.name = ? OR students.name = ?', name, name) }
```

To handle an array of names, you could modify it as follows...

```
scope :by_name, ->(*name) do
  name = name.flatten
  joins("left join teachers on person_type = 'Teacher' and person_id = teachers.id")
  .joins("left join students on person_type = 'Student' and person_id = students.id")
  .where('teachers.name IN (?) OR students.name IN (?)', name, name) 
end
```

this will let you do

```
item.by_name('Smith')
item.by_name('Smith', 'Jones')
item.by_name(['Smith', 'Jones'])
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out! If there is no better answer this will have to do it, thanks!

Comment: hi, i just found out error when sending more than 1 name in scope, example: Item.by_name(["a","b"] would return: (Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s):
do you know any work around?
@SteveTurczyn